# Customize UINavigationBar buttons and images by changing size and position

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, customization

I'm trying to create an app for reading Audio, Video and Doc (PDF).
I chose a design, in which top navigation bar needs to be customized completely.
Like back button and right edit button is much lower than usual and navigation bar background image is much bigger than the usual size (Height = 88 pixel).
I tried a sample project with these spec.
I implemented it in a certain way that :

Navigation bar is set to hidden and placed an imageview with my large sized image. And a custom button is added as subview in the view with navigation controller action.
Code to set image view is as follows :

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 88)];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"top_bar.png"];
[imgView setImage:img];
[self.view addSubview:imgView];
```

Code to set back button is as follows :

```
UIButton *navigationButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[navigationButton setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[navigationButton addTarget:view action:@selector(backButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
navigationButton.frame = CGRectMake(-2, 23, 75, 55);
[self.view addSubview:navigationButton];
```

It works fine.
But when I went through some links, I found that there is a chance of appstore rejection if navigation bar is customized.

Can any one suggest me a proper method for doing this or Can I go ahead with this method.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html). There are no words about rejecting for customizing UINavigationBar. But there is a below phrase.

```
If your user interface is complex or less than very good, it may be rejected
```